# Disable bar button if file doesn't exist

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I have a view with a bar button on it, connected via an IBAction (showMovie) and an IBOutlet (moviebutton). I have managed to make it display a movie via the IBAction, but I would like to check if the movie file it will display exists when the view loads, and, if it doesn't, disable the bar button. I've tried this code in viewDidLoad, to no avail:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:movfilepath ofType:@"mov"]]) {
    moviebutton.enabled = YES;
} else {
    moviebutton.enabled = NO;
}
```

It doesn't give me any errors, it just doesn't do anything. Anyone have any idea as to how to make this work?

EDIT: nicktmro, I've tested it, and it isn't nil, it said "Movie Button is [< UIBarButtonItem: 0x464e190>]".

ANOTHER EDIT: I forgot to mention, I'm using an NSString variable to store the movie file's path (movfilepath), it works fine if I hand it a dummy string (@"dummypath"), but when I use the NSString variable it doesn't work! Anyone have ANY kind of idea on how to make this work???

YET ANOTHER EDIT: Come on! Isn't there ANY answer to this? I thought it was just a simple question, that would take no time at all to answer.

YET ANOTHER EDIT???: I've figured it out on my own, for some random reason the path was fine for the movie player function, but null for everything else. So I got my parentviewcontroller to disable the button instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the movieButton is not nil in
    moviewbutton.enabled = YES;

Print the movieButton with `NSLog(@"Movie Button is [%@]", moviebutton);` just before your if test.

By the way, you are not consistent with your spelling: once you call your button `movieButton` and once you call it `moviebutton` (all lower case).

Cheers...

Comment: I didn't spot that mistake, thanks! It's supposed to be moviebutton (without the capital B). I'm not at my computer right now, but I'll test it asap.

Comment: I've tested it, and it isn't nil, it said "Movie Button is [<UIBarButtonItem: 0x464e190>]".

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Have you tested the code above with a file name that doesn't exist and the button was still enabled? e.g. just paste this and give it a go: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fakeMovieFile" ofType:@"mov"]]

Comment: Yes I have, and it works great with the fake movie path, but my resource name is a NSString, and when I use that, it doesn't work...

Comment: In my above comment, I meant the parent view controller passes the path as a NSString to the view controller with the button. The NSString works perfectly (it plays the movie), but the app crashes if the movie doesn't exist, which is the whole point of disabling the button.